# facebook event venue only shows the city

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to create a facebook event. I'm sending full venue Informations but the map only shows the city instead of the full address. Has anybody an idea what is going wrong?

Both Parameters are doing the same, but not the correct.
I want to see the correct place where the event is starting when i send the correct data to facebook.

```
[name] => $name
[start_time] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2013-06-27 22:00:00
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
    )
[description] => $description
[end_time] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2013-06-28 04:00:00
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
    )

[street] => $street
[city] => $city
[zip] => $zip
[country] => $country
[latitude] => $latitude
[longitude] => $longitude
[location] => $locationString
[privacy] => OPEN
)
```

second try

```
[name] => $name
[start_time] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2013-06-27 22:00:00
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
    )

[description] => $description
[end_time] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2013-06-28 04:00:00
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
    )

[venue] => Array
    (
        [street] => $street
        [city] => $city
        [zip] => $zip
        [country] => $country
        [latitude] => $latitude
        [longitude] => $longitude
    )

[location] => $locationString
[privacy] => OPEN
)
```

Comment: I had a same issue, filed a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/512618168766344) on Facebook and it was closed due to less developer interest in it. So, either you may **file another bug request** or **accept it as design**.

Comment: Does it mean i don't have any chance to show the correct location on map? I've seen you can search a venue, but i didn't find the correct way to get the data which i need.

Comment: Seems to me that Facebook performs some data translation due to which a lot of venue data is lost, if we retrieve data from Facebook to locate the position on the map, it would be at an entirely different place. Additionally You may retrieve the `venue`'s co-ordinates if that would suffice your need.

Comment: arent longitude and latitude the co-ordinates what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, but they are the coordinates I am talking about, but as I said earlier, they are a bad rough estimate. Until Facebook changes what it is doing